# Creating like/dislike system on java/spring

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, rating

**Like/dislike system.**

App has entity Post. Post has field List likes and it joins table, which has columns post_id, user_id.

When User presses button "like" app will add authenticated user in List in PostService. But I need to have the "isLiked" boolean field. This will define what the Like button will look like in frontend.
I can get value for field *countLike* just call method *size()* from field *likes*.

But I don't know now I can get value for field "isLiked".
Help me with it, please.

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    //some fields...

    //there I saved users, who has posed "like"
    private List<User> likes;

    @Transient
    private int countLike;
    
    //there I want to save status - liked/disliked;
    @Transient
    private boolean isLiked;
}
```

```
@Service
public class PostService {
    //some fields and methods...

    public void createLike(int postId, User authenticatedUser) {
        Post post = postRepository.getOne(postId);
        post.getLikes().add(authenticatedUser);
        this.update(post);
    }
}
```

Comment: `isLiked` can be found out by checking `countLike > 0`

Answer (score 3):

While the approach hinted to by yourself and the comment by "Lino - Vote don't say Thanks" will work, I don't think they are a very good idea.

### Working but wastful.

You can create methods like the following:

```
public int likeCount{}{
    return getLikes().size();
}

public boolean isLiked(){
    return getLikes().size() > 0;
}
```

The problem with that is, it will load a lot of data just for providing a single number of even just a single bit of information.

## More efficient in most scenarios

Instead I recommend loading the information from the database.
Assuming you are using Hibernate as the JPA implementation you can do that with the [`@Formula` annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html). With this the relevant code looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Formula("(select count(user_id) from Likes l where l.post_id = post_id)")  
    private int countLike;
    
    
    public boolean isLiked(){
        return getCountLike() > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about annotation @Formula. It helped me.
But field isLiked must return for each user different. If user has liked post already - returning true, else - false.